# jQuery hover detection through another element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

I am trying to make a custom jQuery drag and drop function for a project of mine.

The problem I'm having is that when dragging on element it is put between the mouse and the drop region and I can't find a decent way of detecting the hover over the drop region through the dragging element without it being offset slightly.

```
$(window).mousemove(function (event) {
    $('.element').css({
        'left' : event.pageX-30 + 'px',
        'top' : event.pageY-30 + 'px'
    });
});
```

The above code moves a simple `<span`> to match the mouse position.

```
$('.dropregion').hover(function () {
    console.log('hover');
}, function () {
    console.log('unhover');
});
```

This is the simple hover detection that I am used to with jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try disabling mouse events on the span using css which should render it transparent to the mouse and allow hover to activate under the span

CSS:

```
.element {pointer-events:none}
```

Reference:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: Wow. This did it. Not sure of support but will do some full testing and put in a different method for unsupported browsers. Thanks :D

Comment: am honestly not sure about full browser support either but I believe you will be OK